# How many non-isomorphic groups of order $5832 = 2^3 \cdot 3^6$ are there?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-algebra

I'm afraid I can't provide much motivation other than personal interest.  I have found David Burrell's very recent [Ph.D. thesis](https://ufdc.ufl.edu/UFE0059747/00001/pdf/0), which identified a transcription error that resulted in an [incorrect published count](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503907/about-the-number-of-groups-of-order-1024) for the number of groups of order $1024$.  Burrell's thesis cites a [2017 survey](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-70566-8_8) of Eick, Horn, and Hulpke which lists all the orders (up to $20000$) whose number-of-groups was unknown, and $5832$ is not on this list.  However, I haven't found a (non-paywalled) source for the actual count.  Does anyone happen to have it?

Comment: It seems that the known numbers of groups for a given order $\leq 20,000$ can now be found at http://groups.quendi.de/ According to it, $2^3 3^6$ appears to be manageable now: there are 29,876 non-isomorphic groups of order $2^3.3^6$.

Comment: The above site is hosted by Max Horn. He has linked [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.4239.pdf) for the algorithm in the solvable case (which of course applies to order $2^33^6$).

Comment: @krm2233 Thanks, I'd be happy to accept an answer with this comment (which wouldn't technically be a link-only answer since it does explicitly give the number).

Comment: @EricWong: just turned my comment into a (very short) answer. I had been wondering if that was the proper thing to do, given the very precise nature of your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the known numbers of groups for a given order ≤20,000 can now be found at:

[groups.quendi.de](https://groups.quendi.de)

a website maintained by [Max Horn](https://www.quendi.de/en/math.html) at Kaiserslautern.

According to that site, $2^3.3^6$ appears now to be manageable: there are 29,876 non-isomorphic groups of order $2^3.3^6$.

Comment: One can discuss whether or not $29876$ groups are really "manageable". I am rather impressed by such a large number. But of course, no comparison with the groups of order $2^{11},\ldots , 2^{14}<20000$ (which are not in Max's list, not even  for $2048$).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is an excellent resource.

Comment: @ErickWong: my pleasure -- I find the extent of the information documented on the site  astonishing.

Comment: @DietrichBurde First, I did not mean for "manageable" to in any way underplay the difficulty of determining that there are 29876 groups of order $2^3.3^6$, nor that a collection of 29876 groups is particularly "manageable". Indeed given that it appears the number of groups of order $2^3.3^6$ was not known in 2017, I intended "manageable" only in the sense that the *question* of how many groups of order $2^3.3^6$ had become tractable. I agree with you that it is not clear that the *answer* is what one might consider manageable!

Comment: @krm2233 Yes, I know. I was just contemplating on the word "manageable", and I still have difficulties sometimes with words or expressions in English.